# How to use tabula to extract the table more details by using python script?

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

This is my code:

```
import tabula

# Specify the path to your PDF file
pdf_path = "path.pdf"

# Use tabula.read_pdf with the default auto method
tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)

# Print each table
for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    print(f"Table {i + 1}:\n{table}\n")
```

And that's the result come out:
[table extracted using tabula (python script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUohx.png)

But in the pdf, the table will look like:
[table i want to extract in pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQN8V.png)

Therefore, I would like to know how to extract the table perfectly like this [sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigqT.png)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by adding the lattice to true will make the table looks better like this:
[table printed out in terminal after using the lattice parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQgCt.png)

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', 
multiple_tables=True,lattice=True)
```

But there are still redundant column for example the Unnamed: 0 at the beginning and the Unnamed: 1 columns at the end.
So, how can i make it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `area` parameter to specify the area where the table exist :

> area (iterable of float, iterable of iterable of float, optional) –
>
> Portion of the page to analyze(top,left,bottom,right). Default is
> entire page.

updated code

```py
tables = tabula.read_pdf(
    pdf_path,
    pages='all',
    multiple_tables=True,
    lattice=True,
    area=[40, 5, 175, 730] # need to be adjusted based on the table position
)
```

Comment: thanks for your sharing, but everytime the position of the table will change[since everytime the pdf given is different], so i can't really specify the position of the table.